# Head is getting deleted in java Linked List

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, nodes, singly-linked-list

Hey I am new in Linked lists and I've written this code of deleteing repeating elements but first two elements are same code crash(I think it's deleting head) like if list contains 1,1,2,3,4,.. it deletes head note and code crashes 
Code is pasted below

```
void duplicate(){
  Node temp = head;
  Node temp2 = null;
  Node del = null;

  while(temp != null && temp.next != null){
    temp2 = temp.getNext();
    while(temp2.next != null){
      if(temp.getData()==temp2.getData()){
        del = temp2;
        //temp2=temp2.getNext();
        deletegiven(del.getData());
      }
      //else
      temp2 = temp2.getNext();
    }

    temp = temp.getNext();
  }
}

void deletegiven(int b){
  Node p=null
  Node c=head;

  if(head!=null){
    while(c.data!=b){
      p=c;
      c=c.next;
    }
  //if (c!=null){
      p.setNext(c.next);
      c.next=null;
    //}
  }
}
```

any help would be really helpful

Comment: The rest of the code may be helpful. Additionally, the stack trace why it crashes.

Comment: *I think* it is not checking last element because `while (temp2.next != null)` - that is, ending loop before checking the last element (`next == null`) // first element: `p = null` `while (c.data != b)` immediately exits, no iteration at all, still `p == null` {{`p`, `c` and `b` are bad names, not very informative}}

Comment: I tried (temp2!=null) it crash also can you suggest something about the other issue if first two elements are same it deletes head and the whole list gets delete

Comment: Post the stacktrace

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at list.deletegiven(list.java:70)
 at list.duplicate(list.java:156)
 at mm.main(mm.java:30)